# Voluntourism in Fiji

Tags: fiji, volunteering

I'm interested in traveling abroad to volunteer, specifically to Fiji. I've done a fair amount of research on organizations that offer services as such (Global Vision International, Frontier), but many of these sites have unclear reputations.

Most of the time these programs seem to not include airfare and require the volunteer to pay. Have any of you awesome people had experience volunteering abroad and if so, are there any good resources to use for searching for programs? As well, do you have to pay to volunteer with most/all of these programs?

Comment: Would you consider elsewhere, or just targeting Fiji specifically?

Answer (score 2):

If you're expecting a volunteering organisation to pay for your airfare too, that's is going to be very unlikely unless you're highly skilled in aspects of relief work such as a degree in medicine or mechanical / civil engineering. Most volunteering work that has a 'tourism' / experience component in it often indeed asks for you to pay for your expenses. In this regard, you're perhaps better off gaining an English as a Second Language (ESL) teacher certification and then applying for teaching jobs.

Comment: Agree, the only organization I know that covers airfares is http://www.globalmedic.ca/index.php who send First Responders to disasters. They have to fundraise for that airfare, so they're not going to use it on a randomly-skilled or fungible volunteer.